# Convert an existing groovy build.gradle file into a kotlin based build.gradle.kts

Tags: groovy, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

my project has two different build.gradle files written with groovy Syntax.
I´d like to change this groovy written gradle file into a gradle file written with Kotlin Syntax (build.gradle.kts).

I´ll show you the root project build.gradle file.

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    //ext.kotlin_version = '1.2-M2'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried several "ways" i found in the internet, but nothing worked. Renaming the file, which is obviously not the Solution, didn´t help. I´ve created a new build.gradle.kts file in my root project but the file isn´t shown in my project. 
Also gradle didn´t recognize the new file.

So my question is: How can i transform my groovy build.gradle file into a kotlin build.gradle.kts and add this new file into my existing project?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Of course renaming won't help. You'll need to re-write it using Kotlin DSL. It is similar to Groovy, but with some differences. [Read their docs](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl), look at [the examples](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples).

In your case, the issues are:

1. `ext.kotlin_version` is not valid Kotlin syntax, use [square brackets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed)
2. All [Kotlin strings](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#strings) use double quotes
3. Braces are required around parameters for [most function calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-usage) (there are exceptions, like [infix functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation))
4. Slighlty different task management API. There are different styles available. You can declare [all the tasks in `tasks` block as strings](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/master/samples/copy/build.gradle.kts), or use a single typed function, as in the example below.

Take a look at the converted top-level `build.gradle.kts`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext["kotlin_version"] = "1.1.51"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01")
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${ext["kotlin_version"]}")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task<Delete>("clean") {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and clear answer. I ´ve implemented the top gradle file and it works well. Thx for that. I´ve read the Docu and had a look at the Samples.

Comment: In fact, i don´t get it all. If i try to convert my 2nd file the same way as you "told" to do. there are several errors like "unresolved References" etc.

For example: 

This is my code: 
android {
    compileSdkVersion ("28")
    buildToolsVersion ("27.0.0")
}
but android and the following is an unknow expression. What is my failure? Is there a docu as well. I´m so sorry for being so dumb. I´m new to this whole area.

Comment: We're here to help. Please, create another question with the issues you have with other file. I guess, most probably you'll need to use `configure<Android...Extension> {}` (I do not know the class), instead of `android`, but let us see it all.

Comment: Is there any advantage of switching to .kts? I'm trying to convert my build.gradle now, and I keep stubbing my toe.

Comment: Probably if you're fine with Groovy then there will be no advantage. Kotlin scripts will be even a little bit slower. However, Kotlin scripts provide better IDE support due to static typing. Moreover (that's totally my IMHO): Groovy is loosing its positions and we'll see more Kotlin support and Kotlin-centric features in Gradle in future.

Comment: I want to point out that there's a [GradleKotlinConverter][1] script to automate some of the more common chores when converting groovy gradle files to kotlin. 


  [1]: https://github.com/bernaferrari/GradleKotlinConverter

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    extra.apply {
      var  kotlin_version = "1.7.10"
      var  navigationVersion = "2.5.0"
      var  hilt_version = "2.42"
    }

//        .kotlin_version("1.7.10")
//    ext.navigationVersion("2.5.0")
//    ext.hilt_version("2.42")
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10")
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //    classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$extra.hilt_version")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url  = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
        maven { url =  uri("https://cdn.veriff.me/android/") }
        flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("clean"){
    delete(setOf(rootProject.buildDir))
}




    import extensions.*
    import java.time.LocalDate
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.*
    
    plugins {
        id(Plugins.ANDROID_APPLICATION)
        id(Plugins.ANDROID)
        id(Plugins.PARCELIZE)
        id(Plugins.KAPT)
        id(Plugins.NAVIGATION_SAFE_ARGS)
        id(Plugins.GOOGLE_SERVICES)
        id(Plugins.CRASH_ANALYTICS)
        id(Plugins.PERFORMANCE_ANALYTICS)
        id(Plugins.DAGGER_HILT)
    }
    
    var applicationName = "abc`enter code here`"
    
    android {
        compileSdk = AndroidConfig.COMPILE_SDK
        bundle {
            language {
                enableSplit = false
            }
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy { force(AndroidConfig.FORCE_STRATEGY) }
            }
            applicationId = AndroidConfig.APPLICATION_ID
            minSdkVersion(AndroidConfig.MIN_SDK)
            targetSdkVersion(AndroidConfig.TARGET_SDK)
            versionCode = AndroidConfig.VERSION_CODE
            versionName = AndroidConfig.VERSION_NAME
            testInstrumentationRunner = AndroidConfig.TEST_INSTRUMENTATION_RUNNER
    
            //javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments['dagger.hilt.disableModulesHaveInstallInCheck'] = 'true'
        }
    
        applicationVariants.all {
            outputs.all {
                var formattedDate = LocalDate.now()//LocalDate.now().format(ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                var outputFileName =
                    "${applicationName}_${buildType.name}_${formattedDate}_v${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            getByName("debug") {
                // minifyEnabled = "false"
                isMinifyEnabled = false
                isTestCoverageEnabled = true
                isShrinkResources = false
                isDebuggable = true
                proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
                testProguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                    "proguardTest-rules.pro")
    //            FirebasePerformance {
    //                // Set this flag to 'false' to disable @AddTrace annotation processing and
    //                // automatic HTTP/S network request monitoring
    //                // for a specific build variant at compile time.
    //                isInstrumentationEnabled = true
    //            }
            }
    
            getByName("release") {
                isMinifyEnabled = false
                isShrinkResources = false
                proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
                testProguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                    "proguardTest-rules.pro")
            }
        }
    
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding = true
            dataBinding = true
        }
    
    //    compileOptions {
    //        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    //        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    //    }
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
            //freeCompilerArgs= ["-Xjvm-default=compatibility"]
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=compatibility")
            // freecompilerargs = List( -Xjvm-default=compatibility)
        }
        flavorDimensions("mode")
    
        productFlavors {
            maybeCreate("Staging")
            maybeCreate("PreProduction")
            maybeCreate("Production")
            getByName("Staging") {
                applicationIdSuffix = ".staging"
                //versionNameSuffix = ".staging"
                
            }
            getByName("Production") {
                dimension = "mode"
                resValue("string", "app_name", "abc")
               
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            resources.excludes += "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
            resources.excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE"
            resources.excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE"
            resources.excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
            resources.excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    
            //   excludes += ['META-INF/DEPENDENCIES', 'META-INF/NOTICE', 'META-INF/LICENSE', 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt', 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt']
    
        }
        dynamicFeatures += setOf(":BuyCryptoModule",":"points")
    
    }
    
    dependencies {
        //includeing file libs
        val daggerVersion = "2.42"
        implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
        implementation(files("geetest_captcha_android_v1.7.1.1_20220308"))
        appModuleDeps()
        kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42")
        // For local unit tests
        testImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.42")
        kaptTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42")
        implementation(files("libs/opencsv-5.2.jar"))
        kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")
        kaptTest("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")
        releaseImplementation("com.github.ChuckerTeam.Chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2")
    }
    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    
            arguments {
                // Make Hilt share the same definition of Components in tests instead of
                // creating a new set of Components per test class.
                arg("dagger.hilt.shareTestComponents", "true")
            }
    
    }
```

Comment: this is the ktx gradle file, u can add configration ,or add directly plugins , dependencies